# Building a Timeline like layout in QT

Tags: c++, qt, timeline

I need to create a timeline like ui using qt which should look similar to the timeline on moviemaker or adobe flash. What i intended was to use a grid layout and add labels for the events.

The layout should be able to zoom, scroll as well as with time should scroll forward.

What is the best approach for such in qt ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [QGraphicsView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html#graphics-view) framework: zooming, scrolling, laying down graphics elements come for free.